# How to implement accessibility support for custom controls in coded ui?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, infragistics

The application that I am using is developed by Infragistics XAML controls, those are third party controls.

How to have accessibility support for this custom controls in coded UI test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh552522.aspx

You can also read a bit here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2011/05/17/enabling-ui-testing-for-third-party-winforms-custom-controls-1.aspx